ListViewBuilder says RangeError
How can I check for range error in for each widget(movie) in listView.Builder
like check if this movie is range error If yes show Container();
code:
ListView.builder(
           shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: nowPlaying.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                        child: CachedNetworkImage(
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          imageUrl:
                              '${TMDB_BASE_IMAGE_URL}w500/${nowPlaying! 
                          [index].posterPath}',
                          errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Image.asset(
                              fit: BoxFit.cover, 'assets/images/4.png'),
                        )),
                
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        );


Have you tried printing the length of the nowPlaying object? It looks like you're hard coded value of 10 is greater than the size of nowPlaying.

itemCount: nowPlaying.length

Yes I've tried got the same error result the value was 20

The collection may be zero based, while the List is not.  The ListView may be asking for an item for index 20, but your collection is 0-19.
